# how to change url to a clean url that works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've been looking for an answer for my problem, however the things I tried didnt work out. What I've been trying to do is to create a beatiful url for this link:

`mywebsite.com/blog_template?slug_url=blog-post-name`

to

`mywebsite.com/blog-post-name`

To achieve this I tried the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog_template/([^/]+)$ /blog_template?slug_url=$1 [L]
```

But my code didnt work... Any advice?

Here’s the full htaccess my website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://91.218.67.117/404/ 
ErrorDocument 500 http://91.218.67.117/500/  
#redirect 404  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]  
#remove php 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want to rewrite this request in backend to `index.php`(OR change it to appropriate file's name in case its some other php file). With your shown samples and attempts please try following `.htaccess` Rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog_template\?slug_url=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?slug_url=$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/500.php
```

***NOTE:*** Please keep your .htaccess file and index.php(OR any php file which is taking rewrite request in backend for that matter) in same path(your root etc).

Comment: Hello there! so first of thanks for your help. I tried your code and it works :) The weird part about this is that when I add my other code from my htaccess it starts to not work again... heres the code:
```ErrorDocument 404 http://91.218.67.117/404/ ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/  RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / #redirect 404  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]  #remove php and add RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]``` 

Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: @NamingHH, kindly do add it to your question and I will take a look then

Comment: okay just did it! :)

Comment: @NamingHH, Thanks for doing so, when you combine my code with yours; which sample link you are hitting? And what is error you are getting, thank you.

Comment: So if i add your code beneath my code the URL is this: ```mywebsite.com/blog_template?slug_url=blog-post-name``` I dont exactly know which error I receive is there a way to display the httaccess errors?

Comment: @NamingHH, ok lets start with few questions here: 1st: Is url changing in browser? 2nd: when you hit this url what error you are getting in browser? eg: 404, 500 etc

Comment: The only thing which is changed from the URL is that the website doesn’t have a .php extension. I don’t get any errors at all.

Comment: So the url looks like this: mywebsite.com/blog_template?slug_url=blog-post-name

Comment: @NamingHH, I understand that but when you hit it on your browser is it changing? Since you mentioned my alone code is working. Request you to please do provide more details and I can try to help you more.

Comment: If I remove everything from my htaccess and put only your code and do some changes then it works exactly how I wanted to be.  The url looks like this: mywebsite.com/slug_url. BUT if I add your code with my code then it wont do any changes. So when I hit on the browser it is not changing as I want it to be. Also if I remove the cache it is not changing

Comment: @NamingHH, Ok, I have merged mine and your rules now, could you please put these rules into your .htaccess file and clear your browser cache and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was close. Just a small fix:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /blog_template?slug_url=$1 [L]
```

This relies on additional rewriting rules to get applied though, since `/blog_template` most likely is *not* a resource the http server can somehow "execute" immediately. So you may want to combine above rule with other rules, which you did not reveal to us, which is why I cannot say anything about that.

If you also want to redirect requests to the "old" URL, then that variant should do:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug_url=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?blog_template$ / [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /blog_template?slug_url=$1 [L]
```

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` _temporary_redirection and to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for you answer. I've tried to use your code but it didn't work. That is what I've put over my current httaccess 

```ErrorDocument 404 http://91.218.67.117/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#redirect 404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]

#remove php and add
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]```

And the code you sended me. Put whatever I try it doesnt work.

Comment: The code I used on htaccess could also look a little bit weird since i used them to test if stuff works. It is currently able to remove .php extension and redirect to 404

Comment: And "doesn't work" means what _exactly_ ?

Comment: it means that the code didn’t change the URL in the website. I also deleted my cache and did a hard reload, but it didn’t work

Comment: Sure, that is not what an internal rewrite does. If you (also) want to externally redirect requests to the "old" URL, have a try with the second, extended variant I added to the answer.